# Protected method not accessible from subclass

Tags: android, kotlin, protected, access-modifiers, class-visibility

I know this has been asked before but my problem is strange and I couldn't find an answer.

I have a parent class where a member is declared protected

```
class BaseContoller<G: BaseContract.BasePresenter, F: BaseModel> {
    protected var presenter: G? = null
    // ...
}
```

In each of `BaseController`'s descendants, I refer to `presenter` with no problem as it is accessible in the same package and subclasses.

One `BaseController`'s descendant has to be extended by other classes too but I have to do one check before of performing certain actions in where `presenter` is referenced again

```
class BackupPrinterController<G: BackupPrinterContract.Presenter, F: BaseModel>: BackupController<G, F>
    private fun startScan() {
        if(this is PrinterAssociationController) {
            PrinterConnection.onConnection = { presenter?.onDeviceConnected(it) }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The strange behaviour comes here, `presenter` is perfectly accessible only without the filter `if(this is PrinterAssociationController)`, with that `if` statement, when the `onConnection` callback is invoked, an `IllegalAccessError` exception is thrown  by `presenter`

Here is the declaration of PrinterAssociationController

```
class PrinterAssociationController: BackupPrinterController<PrinterAssociationContract.Presenter, PrinterAssociationModel>(),
PrinterAssociationContract.View
```

and here is the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'package.common.base.BaseContract$BasePresenter package.common.base.BaseController.getPresenter()' is inaccessible to class 'package.project.features.shared.controllers.BackupPrinterController$startScan$1' (declaration of 'package.project.features.shared.controllers.BackupPrinterController$startScan$1' appears in /data/app/package.project-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
    at package.project.features.shared.controllers.BackupPrinterController$startScan$1.invoke(BackupPrinterController.kt:53)
    at package.project.features.shared.controllers.BackupPrinterController$startScan$1.invoke(BackupPrinterController.kt:35)
    at package.project.utils.print.PrinterConnection$scan$1$4.accept(PrinterConnection.kt:84)
    at package.project.utils.print.PrinterConnection$scan$1$4.accept(PrinterConnection.kt:24)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:63)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFilter$FilterObserver.onNext(ObservableFilter.java:52)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDistinct$DistinctObserver.onNext(ObservableDistinct.java:85)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.mixed.CompletableAndThenObservable$AndThenObservableObserver.onNext(CompletableAndThenObservable.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.tryEmit(ObservableFlatMap.java:265)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:562)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:101)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:62)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onNext(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:60)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66)
    at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.serialization.FIFORunnableEntry$1.onNext(FIFORunnableEntry.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onNext(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:60)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onNext(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:58)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66)
    at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.operations.ScanOperationApi21$1.onScanResult(ScanOperationApi21.java:77)
    at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper$1.run(BluetoothLeScanner.java:471)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at com.osama.firecrasher.FireLooper.run(FireLooper.kt:39)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1500)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1390)
```

I don't understand why this is happening when I put that `if` statement

Comment: What is the signature of PrinterAssociationController?

Comment: @mightyWOZ, I just updated the question, but the exception is thrown from the parent, `BackupPrinterController`

Comment: Looks like a compiler's epic fail. Can't test it atm but this seems interesting.